# Cannot encode 0th element of array in php

Tags: php, file-upload, multiple-file-upload

I am working on a php script for multiple file uploading and getting json data from server for the file uploaded. However, the json response is not coming how it is supposed to be

php script

```
$con= new mysqli('localhost','root','','app');

$name='Dp User id ';
if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'])&&!empty($_POST['id']))
    {
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $files=$_FILES['files'];

        $response=array();
        $uploaded=array();
        $failed=array();

        $allowed=array('txt','jpeg','sig','pak','dll','jpg');

        foreach($files['name'] as $position=>$file_name)
        {

            $file_tmp=$files['tmp_name'][$position];
            $file_size=$files['size'][$position];
            $file_error=$files['error'][$position];

            $file_ext1=explode('.', $file_name);
            $file_ext=strtolower(end($file_ext1));

            if(in_array($file_ext,$allowed))
            {
                if($file_error===0)
                {
                    if($file_size<=2097152)
                    {
                        $file_name_new=$name.$id.'.'.$file_ext;
                        $upload_url =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app2/User Files/User Id-'.$id.'/';
                        $file_destination=$upload_url.$file_name_new;
                        $Sql_Query = $con -> prepare("UPDATE profile SET pic= ? WHERE id = ?");
                        $Sql_Query -> bind_param("si", $file_destination,$id);
                        $sql = $Sql_Query -> execute();

                        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$file_destination))
                              {

                                //$uploaded[$position]=$file_destination.'<br>';
                                array_push($uploaded,array($position=>$file_destination.'<br>'));
                        }else{
                              $failed[$position]="[{$file_name}] failed to upload".mysqli_error($con).'<br>';
                        }
                    }else{
                          $failed[$position]="[$file_name] is too large.".mysqli_error($con).'<br>';
                    }
                }else{
                      $failed[$position]="[$file_name] has error {$file_error}".mysqli_error($con).'<br>';
                }
            }else{
                  $failed[$position]="[$file_name] has {$file_ext} which is not allowed".mysqli_error($con).'<br>';
            }
    }

        if(!empty($uploaded))
        {
             echo (json_encode(array(
               "success"=>1,
               "message" => $uploaded)));
        }

        if(!empty($failed))
        {
          echo json_encode(array(
            "success" => 0,
            "message" => $failed));
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
```

I want json to be returned for this script like this

```
{"success":1,
"message":[{"C:\/Apache24\/htdocs\/app2\/User Files\/User Id-94\/Dp User id 94.jpg
"},
{"1":"C:\/Apache24\/htdocs\/app2\/User Files\/User Id-94\/Dp User id 94.jpg
"},
{"2":"C:\/Apache24\/htdocs\/app2\/User Files\/User Id-94\/Dp User id 94.jpg
"}]}
```

but the json is coming like this

```
 {"success":1,
"message":[["C:\/Apache24\/htdocs\/app2\/User Files\/User Id-94\/Dp User id 94.jpg
"],
{"1":"C:\/Apache24\/htdocs\/app2\/User Files\/User Id-94\/Dp User id 94.jpg
"},
{"2":"C:\/Apache24\/htdocs\/app2\/User Files\/User Id-94\/Dp User id 94.jpg
"}]}
```

The 0th element is between the array, and i want it to be between object like the rest. Whenever i choose files and upload it, the 0th one always end up showing like this in response.Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check that `$position` is actually `0` on the first loop, you could try `print_r($_FILES['files']['name']);`

Comment: Check the type of `$position` variable that you set as a key for your `$uploaded` and `$failed` arrays. When all the keys are a zero-based sequence of integers php array gets encoded as JSON array, but if your keys are strings or a mixed bag of numbers and strings - you will get a JSON object.

Comment: but i want $position variable to be integer @VytautasLozickas

Comment: You mean you want JSON objects to have keys as integers?

Comment: I tried to loop it from 1 also, but then only 2 files are showing up instead of 3 if i upload 3 @NigelRen

Comment: yes, like the 1st and 2nd element of message array @VytautasLozickas

Comment: But 1st and 2nd element keys are not integers, those are strings in your JSON output. Try casting your $position variable when setting your `$uploaded` and `$failed` arrays like so `array_push($uploaded,array((string) $position=>$file_destination.'<br>'));` and `$failed[(string) $position]=...` and see if your result changes

Comment: Oh, I get it, i think that we cannot assign integer as key in json array, i tried to put integer with string and now i get all 3 as object thanks @VytautasLozickas,

Comment: It's not that JSON does not support that, it's just that php array with integer keys starting from 0 gets encoded as JSON array but not JSON object and if you have php array with string keys or integer keys not starting from 0 (I think that's actually your case here) - you will get an object from json_encode.

Comment: Oh, Now i get it, thanks @VytautasLozickas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php array with integer keys (including implicitly cast strings) starting from `0` gets encoded as JSON array but not JSON object. Meanwhile php array with string keys or integer keys **not starting from 0** (I think that's your case here) will get encoded into JSON object by `json_encode`.

In your case you have two options:

- If you want your output to contain all objects instead of array for 1st (0) 
  element, just increase your `$position` variable by `1` when pushing elements 
  into your `$uploaded` and `$failed` arrays:

  ```
  array_push($uploaded,array($position+1=>$file_destination.'<br>'));
                                      ^^

  $failed[$position+1]=...
                   ^^
  ```

  That of course will result in 1-based instead of zero-based list in your JSON output.
- Alternatively you can also pass `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` as a second parameter to `json_encode` but that will get rid of your outer array for `message`...

Comment: I tried to loop it from 1 also, but then only 2 files are showing up instead of 3 if i upload 3, this is coming up 
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\Apache24\htdocs\app2\fileUpload.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\Apache24\htdocs\app2\fileUpload.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\Apache24\htdocs\app2\fileUpload.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\Apache24\htdocs\app2\fileUpload.php on line 23   For ex- like this-  {"success":1,"message":[{"1":"rough\/1.jpg
"},{"2":"rough\/2.jpg
"}]}    There is no 0th element

Comment: I mean there is no 3rd element

Comment: Thanks for this !